# Count tags in web page HTML code

Tags: vba, excel

How i can count number of tags in HTML web site code?
I try to use this code:

```
f=ie.document.getElementsByTagName("p") 
MsgBox f.count
```

But it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("p").length
```

If you want to count tags in html page use jquery ".length" it gives you length of the all tags in html page.

Answer (score 0):

Use length property of javascript or if f is an vba's array use this https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.array.length(v=vs.110).aspx